# Observable, with Rx-Realm and Rx-Swift, doesn't stop firing [unless I enter .replay(n)]

Tags: ios, swift, realm, rx-swift

I have the following Realm Object:

```
class GeolocationObject: Object {

    dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString

    dynamic var latitude: Double = 0
    dynamic var longitude: Double = 0

    let addresses = LinkingObjects.init(fromType: AddressObject.self, property: "geolocation")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

I also have the linking Address Object (for simplicity reasons I have only a road property):

```
class AddressObject: Object {

    dynamic public var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var road: String = ""
    dynamic var geolocation: GeolocationObject?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

As you can see I have a To-One Relationship with the `GeolocationObject` and for the needs of my application there is a chance that on the same Geolocation, I may have many `AddressObjects`. So there is a `LinkingObjects` property in my `GeolocationObject`.

I have created a reactive abstraction layer with RxSwift and RxRealm (`RealmProvider` just provides a method for easier Realm write transactions):

```
class GeolocationViewModel {

    let disposeBag: DisposeBag
    let geolocationObject: GeolocationObject
    let id: String

    var latitude: Variable<Double>
    var longitude: Variable<Double>

    let addresses: Observable<[AddressViewModel]>

    init(geolocationObject: GeolocationObject) {

        self.disposeBag = DisposeBag()
        self.geolocationObject = geolocationObject
        self.id = self.geolocationObject.id

        self.latitude = Variable(self.geolocationObject.latitude)
        self.longitude = Variable(self.geolocationObject.longitude)

        self.addresses =
            Observable.array(from: self.geolocationObject.addresses)
                .map({ $0.flatMap({ AddressViewModel.init(addressObject: $0) }) })    

        self.latitude.asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (latitude) in
                RealmProvider.commitWrite {
                    self.geolocationObject.latitude = latitude
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        self.longitude.asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (longitude) in
                RealmProvider.commitWrite {
                    self.geolocationObject.longitude = longitude
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    }

}
```

and

```
class AddressViewModel {

    let disposeBag: DisposeBag
    let addressObject: AddressObject
    let id: String

    var road: Variable<String>

    var geolocation: Variable<GeolocationViewModel?>

    init(addressObject: AddressObject) {

        self.disposeBag = DisposeBag()
        self.addressObject = addressObject
        self.id = self.addressObject.id

        self.road = Variable(self.addressObject.road)

        if let geolocationObject = self.addressObject.geolocation {
            self.geolocation = Variable(GeolocationViewModel.init(geolocationObject: geolocationObject))
        } else {
            self.geolocation = Variable(nil)
        }

        self.road.asObservable()
            .debug()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (road) in
                RealmProvider.commitWrite {
                    self.addressObject.road = road
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        self.geolocation.asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (geolocationViewModel) in
                RealmProvider.commitWrite {
                    self.addressObject.geolocation = geolocationViewModel?.geolocationObject
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

}
```

As you can see I have passed the `LinkingObjects` property as an `Observable`, so in case something changes, it will be notified.

To cut a long story short, I create an address with a geolocation object.
All is fine till now. I grab the `AddressViewType`, and I change the road (which is a `Variable`). If I have a subscription on the `AddressViewType` array through the `GeolocationViewType`, it is correctly notified, but it fires all the time.

For example:

```
let geolocationViewModel = GeolocationViewModel(geolocationObject: GeolocationViewModel)
let addressViewModel = AddressViewModel(addressObject: AddressObject())
addressViewModel.road.value = test1
addressViewModel.geolocation.value = geolocationViewModel

geolocationViewModel.addresses.subscribe(onNext: { addressArray in

print(addressArray[0].road) 

})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

If I try to change the road on the addressViewModel like this:

```
addressViewModel.road.value = "Test2"
```

it correctly notifies the print statement and it prints. BUT it fires all the time with the new value! It doesn't send the print only once.

I found that it stops if the `Observable` for the addresses on the `GeolocationObject` is like this:

```
self.addresses =
                Observable.array(from: self.geolocationObject.addresses)
                    .map({ $0.flatMap({ AddressViewModel.init(addressObject: $0) }) })
                    .replay(1)
```

Later on I also added `.share()`
Why does it fire all the time if I don't put `.replay(1)` ?
Shouldn't it just send it once and stop?

Comment: Hi Theo, I've pasted all the code from your question into an empty Xcode project and when I run it exactly how you describe the code emits once "Test2" and then nothing more happens. You can do it too to test just that isolated piece of code. Maybe you have some other app logic that reacts to changes and modifies back the address or location objects?

Comment: Hi @MarinTodorov thanks for taking the time to check the code. It is very weird actually. Take a look at this ticket too: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealm/issues/64 It is almost identical. Maybe they are connected issues (or there is something in the logic that I have to correct)

Comment: @MarinTodorov also do you believe that an abstraction like the one I tried to create is useful, or should I better work with Realm Objects directly? Thanks for helping.

Comment: We mostly recommend using the Realm objects directly - in that case you're really making the most out of Realm. Only in rare cases when you have to repeatedly transfer objects between threads and those don't change dynamically it might be worth translating the realm objects into structs. If you have the code that reproduces a problem, do open an issue on GitHub so we can track it and try to solve it.